# Making an animation out of an array

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a forest fire simulation in python and I'm struggling to display it as an animation. My code is

```
import numpy as np
from Lib import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class Forest:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.trees = np.zeros((self.height, self.width, 3), dtype=np.float32)
        self.images = []

    def simulate(self, iterations):
        for i in range(iterations):
            for j in range(self.height):
                for k in range(self.width):
                    #some logic goes here
            self.images.append(plt.imshow(self.trees / 255, animated=True))

    def update_fig(self, j):
        global im
        im = self.images[j]
        return im


f = 0.000005
p = 0.01

forest = Forest(100, 100)
forest.simulate(500)

fig = plt.figure()
im = forest.images[0]
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, forest.update_fig, interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

However using this code I get a
*'AxesImage' object is not iterable* error. I figured that problem lies in *update_fig* function, I just don't know what exactly causes it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot needs to be iterable. If you put `[ ]` in this line:

`self.images.append(plt.imshow(self.trees / 255, animated=True))`

to `self.images.append([plt.imshow(self.trees / 255, animated=True)])`

It should work. <s>Other relevant point is the you seem to be using 3D arrays. I'm not sure those will work with float types. Change them to `uint8` and make sure your arrays are RGB color triplets</s>.

**EDIT**: As mentioned by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this will indeed work with float arrays. Made a bad assumption.

These are the changes I recommend (I've put comments in the lines that require you attention):

```
import numpy as np
from Lib import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class Forest:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.trees = np.zeros((self.height, self.width, 3), dtype=np.uint8) #uint since you are using 3D arrays
        self.images = []

    def simulate(self, iterations):
        # for i in range(iterations):
        #     for j in range(self.height):
        #         for k in range(self.width):
        #             #some logic goes here
        for i in range(iterations):
            self.trees = np.random.randint(0, 255, (self.height, self.width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            self.images.append([plt.imshow(self.trees / 255, animated=True)]) # add the [] since it needs to be iterable

    def update_fig(self, j):
        global im
        im = self.images[j]
        return im


f = 0.000005
p = 0.01

forest = Forest(100, 100)
forest.simulate(500)

fig = plt.figure()
im = forest.images[0]
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, forest.update_fig, interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The second point about arrays needing to be ints is not correct. They can be float arrays [0. ... 1.] or int arrays [0 ... 255].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks. I wasn't sure. I'll edit the answer.